# How to accept xml file in via http post method and parse request headers.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am sending Xml file from web broser rest client. I need to accept xml file in asp.net web api http post method.

How do I get xml file content , its file name  and headers content from asp.net web api http post method.?

I referred a few msdn links such as http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2 , i did not get this tutorial

somehow i wrote code

```
HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
var task = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

task.Wait();
Stream requestStream = task.Result;

string inp = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
string result = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
try
{
    Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"c:\\test\\1.xml");
    requestStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
    requestStream.Close();
}
catch (IOException)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException("A generic error occured. Please try again later.", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

through this above code i don't get full xml content.

I am completely new to asp.net web api and .net framework. 
Please provide procedure to implement this and code.

Comment: How do you send it? As a file upload? In a POST? What do you mean "don't get full xml content"? What's missing? What do you get?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am sending via http post file upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are posting the XML file via File Upload, then [this link at www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2) should help.  Otherwise, if you are simply posting a string then you shouldn't need to do anything special other than supply a string parameter in your controller method to receive the XML string (in which case Web API will automagically do the mapping for you).

Comment: I am posting xml file via file upload